# How to fix my if, elif, else statement in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am working on an omegle simulator for fun, where it asks your age and if you're old enough asks you if you have kik. It works fine if your age is 16 or more but if you say any less than that, it comes up with an error. This is the code:

```
age = input("age?\n")
if age == "1":
    print ("Too young bby")
elif age == "2":
    print ("Too young bby")
elif age == "3":
    print ("Too young bby")
elif age == "4":
    print ("Too young bby")
elif age == "5":
    print ("Too young bby")
elif age == "6":
    print ("Too young bby")
elif age == "7":
    print ("Too young bby")
elif age == "8":
    print ("Too young bby")
elif age == "9":
    print ("Too young bby")
elif age == "10":
    print ("Too young bby")
elif age == "11":
    print ("Too young bby")
elif age == "12":
    print ("Too young bby")
elif age == "13":
    print ("Too young bby")
elif age == "14":
    print ("Too young bby")
elif age == "15":
    print ("Too young bby")
else:
    kik = input("Do you have kik?\n")
yes = "yes"
if kik == yes:
    print ("add me bby")
else:
    print ("bye")
```

The error that comes up is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Public/Documents/python/omegle.py", line 36, in <module>
    if kik == yes:
 NameError: name 'kik' is not defined
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: For heavens sake, please cast the age to an integer and just use `if age < 16:`.

Comment: You need more indentation; it's important in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you only set `kik` in this block:

```
else:
    kik = input("Do you have kik?\n")
```

If this block isn't reached, `kik` doesn't exist. An option is to set it before your if/elif blocks.

---

Additionally, you can make this much shorter:

```
kik = "no"
age = input("age?\n")
if int(age) < 16:
    print ("Too young bby")
else:
    kik = input("Do you have kik?\n")
yes = "yes"
if kik == yes:
    print ("add me bby")
else:
    print ("bye")
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you should fix here. FIrst, store the age as a number using `int()`:

```
age = int(input("age?\n"))
```

And then do a less than:

```
if(age < 16):
  print ("Too young bby")
else:
  kik = input("Do you have kik?\n")
  if kik == "yes":
    print ("add me bby")
  else:
    print ("bye")
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `kik` to the default it should be outside your chain.

```
age = input("age?\n")
kik = "no" #assuming no is default
...
```

As it is in your code, it will only be defined if you hit `else`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that `kik` is out of scope, and putting `kik = "no"` at the beginning of your program should get rid of that error.

But, here's a better way to do the whole thing:

```
age = int(input("age?\n"))
kik = "no"

if age < 16:
    print ("Too young bby")
else:
    kik = input("Do you have kik?\n")

if kik == yes:
    print ("add me bby")
else:
    print ("bye")
```

Comment: _"The short answer is that yes needs to be in quotes"_. I don't know about that. The condition should be equally valid whether you use the string literal `"yes"` or the variable named `yes`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I thought the traceback was complaining about `yes` being out of scope, not `kik`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Andy's post was very helpful to me. There is one thing I would add. If you enter an integer less than 16 to the first question, you get both print ("Too young bby") and print ("bye"). The first output only is sufficient for my use, not print ("bye").
To achieve this you indent the second 'if' statement to the first 'else' statement.
If you do not indent my code, you get "You are not eligible to vote in Ireland." twice. Here is my example;

```
Citizen = "No"
Yes = "Yes"
Age = int(input("What is your age?: \n"))
if (Age) < 18:
    print("You are not eligible to vote in Ireland.\n")
else:
    Citizen = input("Do you hold Irish Citizenship? Yes/No: \n")
    if Citizen == Yes:
        print("You are eligible to vote in Ireland.\n")
    else:
        print("You are not eligible to vote in Ireland.\n")
```